# How to quote string of special characters?

Tags: bash, shell

In a shell script I would like to quote this string of special characters `\'%"\"'\` How do I escape the quotes/backslashes inside the string ?

Comment: What is the literal value of your string? Does it really contain those backslashes, or is that your attempt at escaping things? Please [edit] your question to show us.

Comment: Thank you Tom. It does indeed contain the backslashes. I've tried to escape each character with a backslash but it's a mess and it doesn't work. The string contains both single and double quotes which seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use single quotes around the whole string, then the only thing you need to worry about is replacing every `'` with `'"'"'`:

```
$ string='\'"'"'%"\"'"'"'\'
$ echo "$string"
\'%"\"'\
```

This means:

- `'` close the previous single-quoted string
- `"'"` a new double-quoted string, containing a single quote
- `'` open a new single-quoted string

The shell concatenates adjacent strings, so you get a single quote where you want it. You can replace the middle part by `\'` but personally I think that's more confusing!